# Xamarin.iOS: Is it possible to "override" image resources from subproject?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm a little bit confused when using images with the same name in main iOS project and a subproject (library)

1. I create an iOS project (main) with bundle resource image 'A.png'
2. I create second project (subproject) with bundle resource image 'A.png' (same name but different image)
3. I change second project type to library and add it to the first project as a reference.

When I build the app and check the result app bundle (and use the image in my app), I see 'A.png' image from subproject library but I expected to see the image that I included in main project. Is this correct behaviour? Is there any way how to "override" the image from subproject?

I planned that the subproject library would be a "base collection" of images and I would use it in several other projects where some of the images will be replaced.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [forms9patch](https://web.archive.org/web/20180919080001/http://forms9patch.com:80/)  and more about it [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/76eb6ea1-5f2f-471c-b2e0-3d075cb63ebd/forms9patch-simplify-multidevice-image-management-in-your-pcl-xamarinforms-mobile-apps?forum=xamarinforms)

It does allow you to do what you need but it is a pay for add-on.
You might do a bit more research to find free options.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this could help me... I have a "base" application with some resources and need to create several "derived" applications only with some bundle images changed...